# How to get a list of all retweeters in Twitter?

Tags: twitter

I have seen numerous companies doing like Twitter lotteries where users got to retweet their tweet and then one of retweeters will get the prize or whatever.
I was wondering now how do they get the list of all retweeters or pick the winner?

I checked Twitter API and found only this thing: [GET statuses/retweets/:id](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/retweets/%3aid) but it returns maximum of 100 retweeters. Is that the only way?

Comment: I know FavStar has some way of doing this, but I'm wondering if they do it by polling.  e.g. http://favstar.fm/users/hipsterhacker/status/78530718464094210

Comment: This is a known [bug in the Twitter API](https://twittercommunity.com/t/paging-is-not-possible-with-statuses-retweeters-ids-json/71298), which they refused to prioritize a fix for.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks likes there's a couple services out there doing almost exactly this.  A quick google pulls up http://onekontest.com/ and there's a few other Twitter contest services, but they all seem to be different levels of broken since they haven't kept up with changes to the API.

As far as the Twitter API itself is concerned, if you were expecting more than 100 responses, I think using [`GET statuses/mentions`](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/mentions) makes the most sense.  That API call returns any mentions of a user, and you can pass the flag `include_rts` to include any retweets of your tweets.  Then, if you wanted to list RTs of a specific tweet, you could check the `in_reply_to_status_id` field in the returned data to see if it matches the original tweet ID. This API call only returns the last 800 status, 200 at a time, so if you expect a bunch of data, you would need to poll the API repeatedly over time to get all the tweets. I imagine services like favstar are doing exactly this, just on a larger scale.

If you're actually looking for code to do something like this, I wrote a sinatra app called [twitter-rss-digest](https://github.com/muffinista/twitter-rss-digest) which handles querying Twitter over time to track different sorts of queries.  It's pretty rough, and doesn't quite handle this specifically, but it might point you in the right direction if you want to code something.

Comment: Very detailed and specific! Answers my question completely I guess. Thank you for explaining this! :)

Comment: But GET statuses/mentions works only for the authenticating user. So with this hack we can find the list of retweeterers only if we have posted the tweet. Is there an other way to get the list of retweeterers from a tweet that is no belong to our personal account?

Comment: @salvador: [not for more than 100 retweeters](https://twittercommunity.com/t/paging-is-not-possible-with-statuses-retweeters-ids-json/71298).

Comment: The link that you provided for `GET statuses/mentions` is not available.

Answer (score 7):

The Twitter API has an [endpoint that returns up to 100 retweeter IDs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-retweeters-ids.html) for a given tweet.

Note that for historical reasons, [that endpoint only returns up to 100 results](https://twittercommunity.com/t/paging-is-not-possible-with-statuses-retweeters-ids-json/71298/5?u=cryptoclimate) and the documentation about the cursor is useless. Twitter refused to fix the situation.

### 2013 note

That said, the first thread on the Developers site that surfaced in a quick google has [@episod](https://twitter.com/episod), a Twitter employee saying:

> You can't likely get to all of them. The data is spread out. Your best bet is to use the REST API to determine many of the users who performed the retweet, but the data will still be constrained.
>
> It's easiest to track retweets as they happen rather than try to find them from the past. Use the [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis) for that.

Answer (score 2):

I like muffinista's method, but I think if you want a 100% complete list of retweets, simply enable the retweet email notifications and write a script that polls the email box for those matching the subject "retweeted one of your Tweets!" and put the data into a table. Do this right from the start.

Answer (score 1):

The site https://twren.ch/ enlists all the retweeters for a given tweet (note that it only enlists retweeters who are direct followers of the source tweeter.) Nevertheless its probably the only public source available.

Comment: any idea how they get this data? they crawl each of the followers timeline?

Comment: it's dead from now :<