# Getting List of Users Who Retweeted a Specific Tweet?

Tags: twitter

I am running a contest on my website... everyone who retweets a specific tweet gets entered:

https://twitter.com/8wayrun/status/402867740286795776

I now have close to 200 retweets on it. How do I get a list of people who retweeted this tweet? I know I can click the retweets link, but it only lists the most recent 20 retweets or whatever. I know the version 1 API had a way to get the list, but that has since been deprecated.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a list of all retweeters in Twitter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316899/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-retweeters-in-twitter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get only 100 most recent retweets using 1.1 api

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweets/%3Aid

> Returns a collection of the 100 most recent retweets of the tweet specified by the id parameter.

More about it you can find here

- https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/19750
- https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11323

The only solution is track retweets via a streaming API, but you can get only new retweets this way.

Comment: Yeah... how do I get beyond the first page of 100?

Comment: You can't 100 is total limit.

Comment: Do any of these premium series like tweetrank or tweetreach let me get the full list? Or do they have the same restrictions?