# How to get a list of retweeters of a retweet?

Tags: java, twitter4j, twitter-rest-api

The title is confusing, I know, but I do not know how else to phrase this question.

Using twitter4j, I am able to get tweets and the list of users who have retweeted that tweet, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgcMt.png)

However, if the tweet is actually a retweet then I am not able to get the list of retweeters. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V4fR.png)

This is the code I am using to get the list of retweeters:

```
if(tweet.getId() > 0 && tweet.getRetweetCount() > 0) {
    try {
        List<Status> statuses = twitter.getRetweets(tweet.getId());
        for (Status status : statuses) {
            System.out.println("\n" + "\t" + "Retweeter ID:" + status.getUser().getId() + "\n" +  "\t" + "Retweeter Name:" + status.getUser().getScreenName()); 
        }
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        //twitter.getRetweeterIds(tweet.getId(), 2, -1);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How do I get the retweeters of a retweet?

Comment: Do you have the twitter API for expected responses? That's the reference you'd want to follow

Comment: @MrJLP 4  I checked the twitter api console. It doesn't give me any result. I am making this call to the twitter api: GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweets/854183122266497024.json

Comment: You're retrieving it as a retweet? How about get the original tweet. I'd imagine that would have it. You need to understand how the API works

Comment: @MrJLP Thanks it worked! I got the original tweet and then found out the user id and screen name of the retweeters.

Comment: Great. I posted an answer for posterity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Twitter4J* is a Java client library that interfaces with the Twitter REST API.
To understand the right call to use it's best to understand the underlying REST API.

Looking at the [Twitter Rest API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference) we can see an API that returns a list of users who have retweeted a particular tweet, [GET statuses/retweeters/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/retweeters/ids).

In your code the *Twitter4J* API you're using, `getRetweets()`, does not return the IDs of users who retweeted.

Looking at the *Twitter4J* [Twitter4J API docs](http://twitter4j.org/en/api-support.html) we find `getRetweeterIds(statusId)` that returns the list of user IDs that retweed a particular tweet indicated by `statusId`.

Comment: Note that [the endpoint only returns up to 100 retweeter IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334420/1269037).