# Why i can't get all retweeters?

Tags: php, api, twitter

In twitter I see 102 retweets, but I get only 94 retweeters.
Why? How can I get 100 retweeters?

I use [twitter-api-php](https://github.com/j7mbo/twitter-api-php) with next parameters:

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweets/tweet_id.json';
$getfield = '?count=100' ;
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$json = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                ->performRequest();
```

Comment: You should clarify whether you want the number of _retweets_ or _retweetERS_

Comment: What is the tweet id? Some possibilities: 8 users either deleted their accounts or they made their tweets private.

Comment: I need retweeters @PatrickQ

Comment: @PatrickQ I think those numbers should always be the same.

Comment: @PatrickQ: can you come up with a situation in which the number of retweets of a tweet would be different from the number of retweeters? I don't see how that can be possible, because a user can only RT 0 or 1 times.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on the Twitter 1.1 API says:

> **GET statuses/retweeters/ids**
>
> Returns a collection of **up to 100 user IDs** belonging to users who
> have retweeted the Tweet specified by the id parameter.

[Link to developer.twitter.com](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-retweeters-ids)

I take this to mean you only have 94 retweeters in this situation. It CAN return up to 100, if they exist. Also it might not count you retweeting your own post, but that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: i.e user made retweet and after that be deleted? And  retweeters quantity left the same ?

Comment: Sounds plausible, don't know enough about the Twitter API personally to say for sure. It must be some small discrepancy like that though.

Answer (score 1):

Protected Retweets are shown as part of the count you see, but you're unable to obtain them or their Retweeters through the API (unless that protected account follows you).

To outline this, I made a [test Tweet](https://twitter.com/Harmon758Public/status/1092851948284448768) and Retweeted it from the same account as well as from a protected account. If you click to see who Retweeted, it'll show the same account, which Retweeted it, and at the bottom, it'll say "1 user has asked not to be shown in this view. [Learn More](https://help.twitter.com/en/safety-and-security/how-to-make-twitter-private-and-public)":

[image: Test Tweet]

The API will also correspondingly return only the single Retweet(er).

Answer (score 0):

Without the tweet ID, we can't tell, but it's well-documented that the [GET `statuses/retweeters/ids` endpoint only returns up to 100 retweeers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334420/1269037), and Twitter has refused to fix that.